# Unable to solve Leverage browser caching

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

When I test my webpage with [google page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) it shows the error "Leverage browser cashing". Which I understand that I should use the browser caching headers.

I googled for a solution added the following code into .htaccess. But I still get the error from the google speed tester. 
*I am using the php framework [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/releases) 5.1.*

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On 
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"     
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

How can I improve my page to use the browser cache efficiently. So that the Google test tool does not show the error anymore?